# Cross fade two instances of wavesurfer.js webaudio with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm looking to find a way to crossfade the audio between two instances of wavesurfer.js in react.

I have a container component that passes an mp3 path down to a wavesurfer instance but I'm looking to control both sources from the same audioContext in the container component (I think?).

I've looked into https://www.npmjs.com/package/crossfade but not sure how to get the source node for each wave instance and pass it to the parent component?

Basic setup:

```
<container>
  <wave song="" />
  <wave song="" />

  <input type="range" ref="xfade">
</container>
```

Then I have the  components setup like this...

```
this.wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);

this.wavesurfer.init({
  container: this.refs.wave
});

this.wavesurfer.load(this.props.song);
```

Sorry for the basic code info but I have everything else functioning and I'm just looking for some info on this functionality please.